# Detect mouse click and change state in React

Tags: reactjs, state, bind

I have a div which is displayed depending upon a variable- eg: `showDiv`. After i set showDiv= true, div will appear.

```
{showDiv && <div id="someid"> text</div>}
```

Have set a timeout to change variable value so that div will disappear after a time (7 seconds)

```
thisState.setState({showDiv:true});
setTimeout(function(){
                thisState.setState({false});
            }.bind(this),7000);
```

How can i add a code to detect any mouse click and change variable based on that ? Requirement is that, div should disappear either
1. after 7 seconds (already done)
2. based on a click event (if user  just clicks on the screen)

Any thoughts ?

Comment: add an `onClick` to the div that sets the state and clears the timeout.

Comment: onClick on that div will work only if user clicks on that particular div right ? what i meant is, if the user clicks anywhere in the screen, div should disappear

Comment: Oh. Right. That's different. Do you want it to block clicks on other elements while the div is visible so that the only effect is to hide the div?

Comment: @Parameswar please see my solution below and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a window event-listener essentially.

```
componentDidMount(){
    window.addEventListener("click", this.hideDiv)
}

hideDiv = () => {
    if(this.state.showDiv){
       this.setState({
          showDiv: false
       })
    }
}
```

Also remember to remove that listener before the component unmounts:

```
componentWillUnmount{
   window.removeEventListener("click", this.hideDiv)
}
```

See working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-silence-snhnw

Comment: You might also want to clear the timeout. As described there's no harm in letting it run, but it's easy to imagine scenarios where you wouldn't want `hideDiv` being called twice.

Comment: Better to use bind `this.hideDiv.bind(this)`